# Ruby: subtract two dates to get Updated at

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, date, time

I am looking for a way to subtract two dates. I am not sure if a regular `-` would work for this. Asuming that works I still need it to show `Updated 5s ago` and not `0h0m5s ago` if the post was updated 5s ago. The same goes for `Updated 3min ago`, I do not want it to show the seconds nor the hours.

So I need the updated at to be as precise as the least precise time unit that is not equal to 0.

- If post was updated less than 1 sec ago show now
- If post was updated < 1 min ago, but > 1 sec ago have format #s
- If post was updated < 1 hour ago, but > 1 min ago have format #m
- If post was updated < 1 day ago, but > 1 hour ago have format #h
- If post was updated < 1 month ago, but > 1 day ago have format #d
- If post was updated < 1 year ago, but > 1 month ago have format #m
- If post was updated > 1 year ago have format #y

Please let me know if I wasn't clear enough.

Thank you.

Comment: `time_ago_in_words` is probably what you are looking for http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-time_ago_in_words

Comment: You might want to take a look at [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html#method-i-distance_of_time_in_words) it seems to do exactly what you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this in view

```
<%= time_ago_in_words(@post.updated_at) %>
```

Answer (score 1):

check at [time_ago_in_words](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/distance_of_time_in_words) method or [distance_of_time_in_words](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html)